# jquery click and append . in append also click and append

Tags: jquery

On click I append a link like `"<a href='#'>Add Fields</a>"`.

After that when click on that particular link then extra fields append only after clicking link, but when I add four text fields and all in front of four fields has a link. When click second link then text field appended after fourth this wrong it can be appended after second text fields.

Comment: Im sorry none of that makes much sense ? add your code and it might help ....

Comment: Sorry, can't understand your english, can you show us your code instead? a fiddle would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().append("<a href='#'>Add Fields</a>");
});
```

Use

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).after("<a href='#'>Add Fields</a>");
});
```

`append()` is good for inserting things at the end on an element, but `after()` is used to insert HTML content after chosen element.

Comment: Stop using `live`!!! Recently I edited the `jquery-live` [info tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-live/info) Please read it.

Comment: @ManseUK crystal ball, you can buy one on ebay if you like.

Comment: @gdoron [for only £5.75](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Crystal-Ball-50mm-Divination-Scrying-Altar-Rituals-/150744369602?pt=UK_Metaphysical_New_Age&hash=item23191089c2#ht_845wt_922)

Comment: @ManseUK. Delivery: Estimated within 3-4 working days. **LOL**